# AWS IOT - Creating a DynamoDB Rule with multiple indexs

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-iot

Sample : [Creating a DynamoDB Rule](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/iot-ddb-rule.html)

My dynamo-db contains the following columns
:**[id], [type], [subtype],....**
AWS iOT rule includes only one key (partition + sort)

The **[id]** is the **partition**

The **[type]** is the **sort**

But the **[subtype]** goes to the **payload**.

How can i add the subtype field to the table indexes?

Comment: Use a Lambda Function to do this

Comment: how?
a lambda function which do what?

Comment: You can create an IoT rule to trigger a Lambda function. The function will be called with the full payload as an object. You then use the AWS SDK to manually write to write to DynamoDB using any schema you want. You didn't ask for this specifically which is why I did not write a proper answer but I can do that if you want

Comment: i am getting an authentication problem...
arn:aws:sts::XXXXXXXXassumed-role/lambda_dynamo_streams/awslambda_924_20160707060735675 is not authorized to perform: dynamodb:PutItem on resource: arn:aws:dynamodb:eu-west-1:xxxxxxxxx:table/TABALE_NAME

Comment: it's ok now. all i needed to do was to add IAM db authentication to the lanbda.